# How is the Themosis framework able to call a function in a class that doesn't exist?

Tags: php, class, static

I was taking a look a the [Themosis framework](http://framework.themosis.com/) for WordPress and saw in their docs that to make a custom post type you would call:

```
PostType::make('slug-books', 'Books', 'Book')->set();
```

I assumed that `PostType` must be a class with a static function `make`. However, looking at [their code](https://github.com/themosis/framework) I found no `PostType` class.

How are they able to call a function in a class that doesn't exist?

I can kind of see how the `Application` class is being used to store `instances` of the classes when they are called, but I don't see how the code above would trigger the classes creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the developer behind the Themosis framework. This "trick" is highly inspired by the Laravel framework where all credits are.

We're using a facade pattern in order to make this working. Basically we use a PHP magic method __callStatic() and behind we make it link the static method to an instance method.

Check documentation over here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.callstatic